# YubiKey + Webauth: userHandle is always null

Tags: security, webauthn, yubikey

When I authenticate using WebAuthn and my YubiKey, the response.userHandle property is always null.  That is the user id and displayName that I registered the credential with does not get returned.  Is this becuase of something I am doing wrong during the registration / authentication process:

```js
async function register() {
  const publicKeyCredentialCreationOptions = {
    challenge: Uint8Array.from("this-is-a-test", (c) => c.charCodeAt(0)),
    rp: {
      name: "Webauthn Test",
      id: "localhost",
    },
    user: {
      id: Uint8Array.from("a1b2c3d4e5f6", (c) => c.charCodeAt(0)),
      name: "just-a-test",
      displayName: "MrUser",
    },
    pubKeyCredParams: [{ alg: -7, type: "public-key" }],
    authenticatorSelection: {
      authenticatorAttachment: "cross-platform",
    },
    timeout: 60000,
    attestation: "direct",
  };

  const credential = await navigator.credentials.create({
    publicKey: publicKeyCredentialCreationOptions,
  });
}
```

This is the code I use to authenticate:

```js
async function authenticate() {
  const publicKeyCredentialRequestOptions = {
    challenge: Uint8Array.from("test", (c) => c.charCodeAt(0)),
    allowCredentials: [
      {
        id: credentialId,
        type: "public-key",
        transports: ["usb", "ble", "nfc"],
      },
    ],
    timeout: 60000,
  };

  const assertion = await navigator.credentials.get({
    publicKey: publicKeyCredentialRequestOptions,
  });

  console.log(assertion);
}
```

What I end up with is:

```
{
  rawId: ArrayBuffer(64),
  id: "U-nitqhlORmmdltp7TLO3i18KNoWsSebFyrtc3OIRvcktvwlz-dJZCA1_1gxXrNHzqReU7xGAHdfVP75N2aJSw", 
  response: {
    authenticatorData: ArrayBuffer(37) {}
    clientDataJSON: ArrayBuffer(101) {}
    signature: ArrayBuffer(71) {}
    userHandle: null
  }
  type: "public-key"
}

As you can see: userHandle is null.  Can anyone tell me why?
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `userHandle` can be null depending on which type of WebAuthn credential the relying party requested to be created.

The default WebAuthn behavior will create a non-discoverable credential and the `userHandle` returned in the assertion will be null. No data is stored on the authenticator for this type of credential so there is nothing to return.

To create a WebAuthn client-side discoverable credential, a.k.a. resident key, you must set the `requireResidentKey` member to `true`. This will store credential data on the authenticator and will return the `userHandle` in the assertion.  Refer to the [AuthenticatorSelectionCriteria in the W3C WebAuthn spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn/#authenticatorSelection) for the details.

Here is an example:

```
authenticatorSelection: {
  authenticatorAttachment: "cross-platform",
  requireResidentKey: true
},
```

See [Yubico's WebAuthn Dev Guide](https://developers.yubico.com/WebAuthn/WebAuthn_Developer_Guide/Overview.html) to learn more about [resident keys](https://developers.yubico.com/WebAuthn/WebAuthn_Developer_Guide/Resident_Keys.html) and the [userHandle](https://developers.yubico.com/WebAuthn/WebAuthn_Developer_Guide/User_Handle.html).

Comment: Excellent - that answers my question - thanks Luke!

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to understand what you are dealing with. I played with https://u2f.bin.coffee/ to get a feeling for the data flow. As a result of authentication I have received a response like:

```
Got response:
{
  "keyHandle": "F74UNCdNv1d43zw7hqxYgkjR3O6dcevopiSb3jrcB3rMFRUM486LbsVExJD0R3ESC5MCb3zeFGdxvS3ksZ7sCA",
  "clientData": "eyJ0eXAiOiJuYXZpZ2F0b3IuaWQuZ2V0QXNzZXJ0aW9uIiwiY2hhbGxlbmdlIjoiTXpPTjhXRHpvSDlhZHU0bTk5YWF0ZyIsIm9yaWdpbiI6Imh0dHBzOi8vdTJmLmJpbi5jb2ZmZWUiLCJjcm9zc09yaWdpbiI6ZmFsc2UsImV4dHJhX2tleXNfbWF5X2JlX2FkZGVkX2hlcmUiOiJkbyBub3QgY29tcGFyZSBjbGllbnREYXRhSlNPTiBhZ2FpbnN0IGEgdGVtcGxhdGUuIFNlZSBodHRwczovL2dvby5nbC95YWJQZXgifQ",
  "signatureData": "AQAAAAUwRAIgEqi5POKKUraU97W3vbfn34DSWqXwiZwEi5g9QPPtS6MCIBbLYW1_b3aRjHQivSRZQUAfBobx6CZnQ0_VVvuu1LJJ"
}
```

Now I assume the `keyHandle` here is your `authenticatorData`, the `clientData` here is your `clientDataJSON` and that `signatureData` is your `signature`. Whatever this `userHandle` is you are missing, it does not seem to be required.

Look at [this picture](https://developers.yubico.com/U2F/Protocol_details/Overview.html) too:

[image: Taken from the page https://developers.yubico.com/U2F/Protocol_details/Overview.html]

If the `userHandle` were the `handle`, the authentication would not work with a `null` value. But it does if I understand your example correctly.

So I believe you are dealing with a field that is reserved for future purposes or other flows than that which you need at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it and replying in such detail.  The userHandle property is indeed apart of the WebAuthn spec but may be be broadly implemented.  I will need to dig further on this I think.